# Is it okay to ask for edits?

Tags: discussion

imho the idea behind this sloppy question is a gem: [Computational Complexity of Not All Equal SAT variant](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77242/computational-complexity-of-not-all-equal-sat-variant#77242)

- Is it allowed to ask in the comments if somebody can edit the question?
- Should there be a way a user can incite anyone to edit a question, such as a bounty?

Comment: Asking for edits is perfectly okay. Unfortunately, there is no immediate way to reward great edits in terms of rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's OK to ask for edits.  That would be most useful if your comment explained specificaly what needed editing.  I don't know of any way to incentivize edits.  You are also welcome to edit it yourself to improve the question, if you can see how to make an improvement.